# Stream Netflix movie from iPhone to Mac

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, airplay, streaming, netflix

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro and an iPhone 8. I use Netflix app on my iPhone and have downloaded a movie in it for offline viewing.

Is there a way for me to stream the movie on my iPhone onto my MacBook? I can use the MacBook's larger screen for better viewing experience.

Can download Netflix on to phone but can't seem to do it on Mac?

Comment: One of the suggestions in the following article might help: https://machow2.com/netflix-on-mac/

Comment: Also, an alternative that did not cross my mind before: there is an app for Windows, so if you have by any chance a Windows laptop you can download it there instead.

Answer (score 6):

[Netflix killed Airplay support on April 2019](https://www.theverge.com/2019/4/6/18298146/netflix-confirms-it-yanked-airplay-support-wont-let-you-beam-shows-to-apple-tvs-anymore), so it is not possible anymore to use AirPlay in a macOS device to stream from a iOS one.

See [this support article](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/49) at Netflix for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Stream from your iPhone or iPad or iPod Touch to your Mac

The Netflix app for iOS supports AirPlay, a proprietary protocol stack developed by Apple, which allows wireless streaming between devices of multimedia content. This means that you can stream Netflix movies and shows from your iOS devices to any AirPlay-enabled devices over local Wi-Fi. And because the app also supports offline downloads, you have everything you need to enjoy Netflix offline on your Mac. Well, almost everything. You also need an app like AirServer so you can receive AirPlay streams on your Mac.

The easiest and proven solution is to access Netflix via Google Chrome browser on your Mac as @Nimesh Neema explained. You can even stream to any TV using Chromecast in Google Chrome browser and with $35 Cast dongle device (at any best buy) that plugs into any TV with HDMI plug.

Comment: IIRC, Netflix app have restriction like non-ability to take snaps and mirror movie playback. Are they no longer applicable?

Comment: Netflix does support using AirPlay as streaming output from iPhone. It works fine with Apple TV. However to receive on Mac one needs to enable the Mac to receive with device like AirServer. Your answer is better, and that is what I use, just log in Netflix on Chrome browser, then I use chromecast to cast to my TV.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the assumption all forms of mirroring and streaming are disabled. Please edit my answer to sort out any inaccuracies and add relevant information.

Comment: Thanks all, seems like I need AirServer. It is only relevant for when I'm working away.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect your iPhone via USB to your Mac and use QuickTime to mirror the screen:

1. Connect your iPhone via USB to your Mac.
2. On your iPhone, if requested, trust your Mac.
3. On your Mac, open a Finder window, select your iPhone in the sidebar and, if requested, trust your iPhone:

   [image]

   If you don't see your iPhone under "Locations", open Finder Preferences > Sidebar and check "CDs, DVDs, and iOS Devices".
4. Open QuickTime Player and select File > New Movie Recording.
5. Click the Options pop-up menu and choose for Camera your connected iPhone.
6. You should see your home screen now.

See [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/quicktime-player/record-a-movie-qtp356b55534/10.5/mac/10.15#apd86177808b0da4) (up to step 6) for more information (note that you don't need to actually click the record button for this to work).

Using this method you don't need any third party apps. However, it's more of a workaround.

Comment: This is a very nice trick, thank you for sharing!

Comment: I had tried this on amazon prime a while ago and no video appears on Mac or the phone. Since this makes way for piracy, they may remove it too @jaume ;)

Comment: this does not work for netflix.

Comment: As of October 2023 this does not work anymore for Netflix: it stops the video as soon as it is connected with the cable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not be possible to stream a movie downloaded in Netflix iOS app onto Mac.

There is no official Netflix macOS app. You can only stream video from Netflix on a desktop computer using a Web browser and Internet connection. It is also not possible to download movie from Netflix website on a desktop computer.

To use [Netflix](http://netflix.com) on macOS, login with your Netflix account using any desktop Web browser (Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox).